# Array values to strings

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to get array values to string, but i fail

My array ($epg) looks like this:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => VGhlIEZhbnRhc3kgRm9vdGJhbGwgQ2x1Yg==
            [lang] => en
            [start] => 1425385800
            [end] => 1425387600
            [description] => Sm9obiBGZW5kbGV5IGFuZCBQYXVsIE1lcnNvbiBwcmVzZW50IGEgZGlzY3Vzc2lvbiBvbiBrZXkgZmFudGFzeSBmb290YmFsbCBpc3N1ZXMsIGFzIHdlbGwgYXMgdGhlIHdlZWtlbmQncyBQcmVtaWVyIExlYWd1ZSBtYXRjaGVzLiBBbHNvIGZlYXR1cmluZyBndWVzdHMgZnJvbSB0aGUgd29ybGRzIG9mIHNwb3J0IGFuZCBzaG93Yml6Lg==
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => QmFyY2xheXMgUHJlbWllciBMZWFndWUgUmV2aWV3
            [lang] => en
            [start] => 1425387600
            [end] => 1425391200
            [description] => QSBsb29rIGJhY2sgYXQgcmVjZW50IGZpeHR1cmVzIGluIHRoZSBFbmdsaXNoIFByZW1pZXIgTGVhZ3VlLCBhcyB0aGUgc2Vhc29uIGNvbnRpbnVlZCB3aXRoIG1hdGNoZXMgYWZmZWN0aW5nIGJvdGggZW5kcyBvZiB0aGUgdGFibGUu
        )

)
Array
(
)
```

And then i create foreach loop, and try to get values like this:

```
$title = $epg['title'];
$lang = $epg['lang'];
echo $lang;
echo $title;
```

But i get errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: title in........ Notice: Undefined index:
>   lang in.........

I am guessing that happens, because i have strange array , these empty arrays at start and end.

If so, how can i fix it?

Regards
M

Comment: buddy you really need to go through the basics

Comment: Maybe share some light how i can get the values to string?

Answer (score 1):

When you define the array like here

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => VGhlIEZhbnRhc3kgRm9vdGJhbGwgQ2x1Yg==
        [lang] => en
        [start] => 1425385800
        [end] => 1425387600
        [description] => Sm9obiBGZW5k...
    )
```

If you don't have title, lang, etc. delcared as variables you need to have

```
[0] => Array
    (
        ['title'] => VGhlIEZhbnRhc3kgRm9vdGJhbGwgQ2x1Yg==
        ['lang'] => en
        ['start'] => 1425385800
        ['end'] => 1425387600
        ['description'] => Sm9obiBGZW5k...
    )
```

Comment: If you get it from some other site you need to know how it works there and with that I cannot help, but the idea above is that writing ['title'] - with the quotes, you add a key in this array that is "title" and give it the value on the right =>. However, written like [title] means add a key that is the value of the variable title. That you can do if you have declared the variable title above - title = "myVariable"; - that way your key in the array this time is "myVariable". So when you use the quotes you give it a string for a key and without a quotes the key is the value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this remove ur empty and then use this

```
print_r(array_filter($epg));

echo $title = $epg['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your array is not empty

```
if (count($epg) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get notices, not errors. But it is good practice to treat them as errors and removing from Your code.

These notices are about undefined indexes, so You have to check if given index is present in current element of array. You can do it like this:

```
$title = array_key_exists('title',$epg) ? $epg['title'] : NULL;
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)